# AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'sqrt'

Tags: python, math

How are you?

I was trying to do a simple code math to practice, but I don't know why this error occurs.

```
import math

number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

for i in range(2, math.sqrt(number)):
    if(number % i == 0):
        print("{} is not prime".format(number))
    elif(number <= 1):
        print("{} is not prime".format(number))
    else:
        print("{} is prime".format(number))
```

Every site said "import math" and it will work, but it's not true, it just doesn't work. My version of Python is 3.9.3, coding in Linux. Thanks for the attention

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hicaro/Documentos/Projects/LearnToProgramPlaylist/stringFunc2.py", line 41, in <module>
    for i in range(2, math.sqrt(number)):
AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

Comment: You most likely named a file `math.py`. Don't do that.

Comment: What are you using to run the code? Also, if you need a work around you can do `** 0.5` should be the same as square root so `int(number ** 0.5)`

Comment: @RolvApneseth thanks, it was helpful, I don't need to import math anymore to get the square root. Have a nice day

Comment: You too but you should find out why `math` isn't working it's a very useful module

Comment: I agree. I'll figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: One thing to try to get more insight about the problem is `dir(math)` after `import math`. If you have imported the built-in `math` module, you will get a list of math functions and other stuff. If you are accidentally importing some other module, you will see something else.